# Adding gazebo_ros_camera to gazebo model

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

How would I add/attach camera to a model (like a cylinder which is defined in the world file) in Gazebo? I know how to add camera to a robot link. But I want to add camera to a standalone model defined in the world file.

Thank You,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355219/adding-gazebo_ros_camera-to-gazebo-model/) by [nihalar](https://answers.ros.org/users/54529/nihalar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-06-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @nihalar,

The short answer: Like the same way you add a camera to any robot model.

The long answer: Is related to the way you use to generate your world. In order to add a camera to a (static) Gazebo model you will need to include the model in the sdf world. Moreover, if you have a xacro macro with the camera you may just copy the model and included in an empty world. In your case you will need to define a cylinder link and attach it to a camera link in which you will define your [camera sensor](http://sdformat.org/spec?ver=1.7&elem=sensor) with the appropiate plugin.

`gazebo_ros_pkgs` contains exactly what you want in a [demo](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/dashing/gazebo_plugins/worlds/gazebo_ros_camera_demo.world) world. This demo world simulates a bounding ball in front of a camera and publish the camera frames over a ROS topic.

For more information about the (camera) gazebo plugin you can check this [tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins#Camera).

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0